# How to clash lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I was looking at one of the trailers for Battlefront. At the end Vader and Luke clash lightsabers. How can I clash lightsabers?

Answer (score 4):

To clash lightsabers both players need to press Triangle/Y (heavy attack) on PS4/XBONE at around the same time

Answer (score 2):

Both people need to be locked on, or close to it, (on Xbox one this is done by pressing in the left stick) and both need to use the strong attack at roughly the same time, then you need to button mash to win the clash.

Comment: They don't need to be locked on. Just aiming in their general direction